# check all the check box

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a table with a lot of checkbox's, but now I want to be able to use a "universal" checkbox.

Like this:

```
<tr>
      <th scope="row">Indice</th>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="check1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="check2"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="check3"></td>
      <td><button onclick="check()">Check Checkbox</button>
          <button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck Checkbox</button></td>  
</tr>
```

Well I've done this on javascript:

```
<script>
function check()
  {
  document.getElementById("check1").checked=true
  document.getElementById("check2").checked=true
  document.getElementById("check3").checked=true
  }
function uncheck()
  {
  document.getElementById("check1").checked=false
  document.getElementById("check2").checked=false
  document.getElementById("check3").checked=false
  }
function selectAll(frmElement, chkElement) {
    // ...
}
document.getElementById("check_all_1").onclick = function() {
    selectAll(document.wizard_form, this);
}
</script>
```

So far so good... but... the ideia is to have some results from a database, and there is no change I'm doing this javascript "check3", "check4" ... how should I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "have some results from a database"?  Do you want to get some data from a database and check only checkboxes required based on that data?  If yes, then you need to read up on AJAX.

Comment: Well, I mean that I'm testing with code only, In the future I'll use the data from the database like "mysql select from ... where ... while..." I really don't know how many check's will be in the future (with the database), so I can't create a "document.getElementById("check1")" for everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple plain-JavaScript (no library required) version:

```
function checks (){
    var button = this.className.indexOf('uncheckAll') === -1,
        row = this.parentNode.parentNode,
        inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            inputs[i].checked = button;
        }
    }

}

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', checks);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Hkqdq/).

The above amended to avoid having to explicitly traverse the DOM (which, using sequential `parentNode.parentNode`... requires an advance knowledge of the HTML structure), using a (simple) `closest()` shim:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.closest = function (tagName) {
    tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
    var self = this,
        selfTag = self.tagName.toLowerCase();
    return selfTag == tagName ? self : self.parentNode.closest(tagName);
}

function checks (){
    var button = this.className.indexOf('uncheckAll') === -1,
        row = this.closest('tr'),
        inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            inputs[i].checked = button;
        }
    }

}

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', checks);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Hkqdq/6/).

References:

- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener).
- [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
- [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function selectAll(chkElement) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('n');
  for(var checkbox in checkboxes)
   checkbox.checked = chkElement.checked;
}
```

Where 'n' is the name

Comment: there is no `for each` :)   it's just `for`, take it out, and you can have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="javascript: return CheckAllCheckboxes(this); ">
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check3">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

JS

```
CheckAllCheckboxes = function (current) {
   var state = $(current).is(':checked');
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('checked', state);
   });
};
```

You can check [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/4KRT6/2/)

**Another option**

With jQuery click event

```
$(':checkbox').not('#checkAll').change(function () {
    $("#checkAll").attr("checked", $(":checkbox").not(":checked").not("#checkAll").length ? false : true);
});
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

You can check [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/yPjKn/)

Comment: jQuery tag is not found in the question.

Comment: Please use any one option from above answer

Answer (score 1):

try this. it will work static as we as dynamically.

```
<table>
     <tr id="trCheck">
         <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1"/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2"/>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <input type="button" name="btnSubmit" onclick="check();" value="Check/Uncheck" />
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>


function check() {

     if ($('#trCheck').find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked') == false)
         $('#trCheck').find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
     else
         $('#trCheck').find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);

 }
```

Comment: You should at least mention this assumed JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If the results are from a database, when you are looping through the database results and adding the checkbox to the page simply do...

```
<td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td>
```

Also, make sure you terminate the tag with a forward slash.

Comment: I may not make myself clear, I know that, I just want a button to check all or uncheck all my checkbox's in the table