# How to work with checkboxes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm relatively new to the concept dealing with checkboxes in jQuery. I have three checkboxes with same name. Now I want to apply some condition depending upon selection of the first checkbox only. For your reference my HTML code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="users"  value="users"/>Users 
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="upload_from_file" value="upload_from_file"/>Upload From File
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="copy_paste_from_excel" value="copy_paste_from_excel"/>Copy paste from excel
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <h4>Users</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" class="user_checkbox" name="user_checkbox" id="all_users" value="all_users"/>all users &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="user_checkbox" name="user_checkbox" id="register_users" value="register_users"/>Register users &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="user_checkbox" name="user_checkbox" id="package_expired" value="package_expired"/>Package expired &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="user_checkbox" name="user_checkbox" id="inactive_from_last_month" value="inactive_from_last_month"/>Inactive from last month
    </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My requirement is when user checks the checkbox having value `"users"` then he/she must select at least one checkbox from the group of checkboxes having values(`"register_users"`, `"package_expired"`, `"inactive_from_last_month"`).

One more condition is that when the user selects the checkbox having value `all_users` all other checkboxes from the same group i.e checkboxes having values(`"register_users"`, `"package_expired"`, `"inactive_from_last_month"`) should be disabled.

One more condition is that when user selects any one of these check boxes the checkbox `"all_users"` should be disabled.

Can anyone help me in achieving this functionality using jQuery? Thanks in advance. You can correct my code if somewhere I'm going wrong in above code. I've also attached the screenshot of UI.

[image]

Comment: Don't use the same id and name multiple times on a page (or form).

Comment: SO is not a site for "please code it for me"... Hire a developer or try to learn/do it yourself. If you are stuck somewhere, just ask a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528005/check-all-the-check-box)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to include the jQuery library to your file if it is not included already. Then just write the below script to make the functionality work you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$("#inactive_from_last_month" ).is(":checked")
$(function(){
  $(".user_checkbox").click(function(){ 
    if($("#all_users" ).is(":checked")) {
      $("#register_users").removeAttr("checked");
      $("#package_expired").removeAttr("checked");
      $("#inactive_from_last_month").removeAttr("checked");
    } else if ($("#register_users" ).is(":checked") || $("#package_expired" ).is(":checked") || $("#inactive_from_last_month" ).is(":checked")) {
      $("#all_users").removeAttr("checked"); }
    });
});
</script>
```